# Solidity Contracts Callback

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I have two contracts, an active contract A is interacting with the external world and many passive contracts P (dynamically added) are designed to trigger some functions when in contract A certain conditions are met.

Therefore contract A is supposed to call a callback function of each of P contracts; I was wondering what would be the best way to `register` a callback function of newly added P into already deployed contract A?

```
contract A{

   uint numberOfContractsAdded;

   struct ToCallBackContracts{
     address contractAddress;
     bytes4 contractMethodToCall;
     bytes32 theOnlyArgument;
   }

   mapping(uint -> ToCallBackContracts) contracts;


   constructor A(){}

   function triggeredFromOutside(bytes32 param)public returns (bool){
     for(var i=0; i<numberOfContractsAdded; i++){
       //2- how? call the callback function of each registered contract
     }
   }

   function registerCallback(bytes4 _cMethod, address _cAddress){
      //1- how? to save contract/method, number of parameters to receive?
   }
}


contract P{
    address addressOfA;
    constructor P(address _addressOfA){
        addressOfA = _addressOfA;
    }

    function _callback(bytes32 param){
       //do something
    }

    function callFromOutsideToRegisterWithA(bytes32 param){
       //3- how? to register with A   
    }

}
```

There are 3 HOWs pointed out in the code for better understanding to summarize the question if I understand it right..

disclaimer: code is not tested/compiled/checked for syntax and only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I think you should have a look at [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48202/how-to-watch-events-on-smart-contract/48205#48205)

Comment: thanks @henk but `events` wont solve the problem at hand, I would need to pass `param` as you notice in `P._callback` signature.

Comment: If all callbacks take the same type and amount of parameters, you could just update the `handleEvent` function to take a parameter and pass it in A. If not, I'll write up another solution

Comment: In some scenarios contract `A` may change the parameter to pass to the contracts so `events` may be a bit unfit for my case

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that, maybe edit your question?

Comment: the actual scenario will be complicated but lets assume that parameter is an integer value received by A when called from outside `triggeredFromOutside` - when `A` is invoking callbacks of registered SCs, it will +1 to the param before passing it to callback of the registered contracts. So its a different value for each contract to be called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80978/discussion-between-henk-and-hammad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with by filling in the blanks and edidting your code as little as possible. The difference with using events in your case, is that for each callback, a different value for `param` can be provided.

I'm certainly not very fond of this architure, as I think you should use interfaces instead, but alas.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract A{

    struct ToCallBackContract {
        address contractAddress;
        bytes4 contractMethodToCall;
        bytes32 theOnlyArgument;
    }

    ToCallBackContract[] public contracts;

    // This mapping is used for finding contracts by their address
    mapping(address => uint256) contractIndexes;

    function triggeredFromOutside() public returns (bool){
        // Don't use var, the compiler wil infer you use uint8, and it might overflow quickly
        for(uint256 i=0; i< contracts.length; i++){
            //2- how? call the callback function of each registered contract

            ToCallBackContract storage toCallBackContract = contracts[i];
            // THIS MIGHT BE UNSAFE, PLEASE BE CAREFUL
            address(toCallBackContract.contractAddress).call(toCallBackContract.contractMethodToCall, toCallBackContract.theOnlyArgument);
        }

    }

    function registerCallback(bytes4 _cMethod, address _cAddress) public {
        //1- how? to save contract/method, number of parameters to receive?

        // Incrementing the lenght of the array creates an empty struct.
        uint256 index = contracts.length++;

        // Fill it up
        contracts[index].contractAddress = _cAddress;
        contracts[index].contractMethodToCall = _cMethod;

        // Register it in the indexes mapping
        contractIndexes[_cAddress] = index;
    }

    // This function sets the argument
    function setTheOnlyArgument(address _contractAddress, bytes32 _value) public {
        ToCallBackContract storage toCallBackContract = contracts[contractIndexes[_contractAddress]];
        toCallBackContract.theOnlyArgument = _value;
    }
}


contract P{
    A addressOfA;
    constructor(A _addressOfA) public {
        addressOfA = _addressOfA;
    }

    function _callback(bytes32 param) public {
       //do something
       emit SomethingDone(param);
    }

    function callFromOutsideToRegisterWithA() public {
       //3- how? to register with A 

       // A function signature is calculated like so:
       bytes4 sig = bytes4(keccak256("_callback(bytes32)"));
       // Then, register it
       addressOfA.registerCallback(sig, this);
    }

    event SomethingDone(bytes32 param);
}
```

To use it, first deploy `A`. The, deploy a `P` using the address of the deployed `A`. After that, call `P`'s `callFromOutsideToRegisterWithA` method. This registers `P` and its `_callback` method with `A`.  To set the value of the argument that is going to be sent to the `_callback` method of `P`, use `A`'s `setTheOnlyArgument` method providing the address of `P` and the value you want `A` to pass to it.

Then, call `A`'s `triggeredFromOutside` method, which whill call each registered `P`'s callback, passing along the given value for `theOnlyArgument`.